# need suggestions for enhancing nested for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 4 levels of categories in my application, and each category will have set of 7 sub categories. So it will be a (7*7*7*7) structure. I need to fetch all the four levels of categories at a service call. My table structure will be as follows,

```
categoryId, categoryName, parentId, active
```

So, for the first level category, I am fetching based on whose parentId is 0 and for rest of three category levels I am fetching based on whose parentId corresponds to categoryId. Finally, I need to return the list of all categories in to a domain object. So my fetching code is as follows,

```
 List<DrmCategory> cate1 = categoryRepository.findByParentId(0);
        cate1.forEach(category -> {
             System.out.println(" Level1 -> Parent ID : "+category.getParentId()+ " Name : "+category.getCategoryName());

             List<DrmCategory> cate2 = categoryRepository.findByParentId(category.getCategoryId());
             cate2.forEach(category2 ->{
                 System.out.println(" Level2 -> Parent ID : "+category2.getParentId()+ " Name : "+category2.getCategoryName());

                 List<DrmCategory> cate3 = categoryRepository.findByParentId(category2.getCategoryId());
                 cate3.forEach(category3 -> {
                     System.out.println(" Level3 -> Parent ID : "+category3.getParentId()+ " Name : "+category3.getCategoryName());

                     List<DrmCategory> cate4 = categoryRepository.findByParentId(category3.getCategoryId());
                        cate4.forEach(category4 -> {
                             System.out.println(" Level4 -> Parent ID : "+category4.getParentId()+ " Name : "+category4.getCategoryName());
                     });
                 });
              }
            );
          }
        );
```

I feel the above code is not the best way to implement the functionality. Can any one give some suggestion to enhance the nested for loop conditions. Or, I would appreciate if someone suggested some better design (table design and nested loop fetching all level categories).

Comment: Do you just want to log? Or do something else? If so what?

Comment: Converting for-each loops into forEach streams is not always a good idea...

Comment: I would create one recursive method calling itself with its depth level as parameter, but that's just me. Some people have troubles with recursion.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. can you please give your inputs to create the recursive method. I will definitely help me

Comment: I would add a self mapping in your entity, which means your entity will have getParent method which will call eagerly its parent (I assume you dont have too much category)

Comment: @assylias, Yes even I notice that this is not a good idea. Can you please suggest me the better Idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can try a recursive method such as this:

```
void recursiveMethod(int currentId, int depth) {

    List<DrmCategory> cate = categoryRepository.findByParentId(currentId);
    cate.forEach(category -> {
         System.out.println(" Level"+depth+" -> Parent ID : "+category.getParentId()+ " Name : "+category.getCategoryName());

        if (depth < 4) {
            recursiveMethod(category.getCategoryId(), depth + 1);
        }
    });
}
```

To be clean, you should call another method to manage your controls depending on the depth. `doSomething(category, depth);`

To begin the recursion, call `recursiveMethod(0,1);`

*Note that this is blind coding, you may find syntax mistakes.*

Comment: Thank you. Will try your suggestion

Comment: If that suggestion worked out for you, make sure to approve the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Using my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```
EntryStream.<DrmCategory>ofTree(null, 
    (depth, cat) -> depth >= 4 ? null : 
        categoryRepository.findByParentId(cat == null ? 0 : cat.getCategoryId()).stream())
    .nonNullValues()
    .mapKeyValue((depth, cat) -> " Level"+depth+" -> Parent ID : "
            + cat.getParentId() + " Name : " + cat.getCategoryName())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The [`EntryStream.ofTree`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#ofTree-T-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method is capable to generate a flat depth-first Stream of tree-like structures in the form of `(depth, element)` pairs. We start with `null` element as the tree root (according to your example seems that you have no special 'root' element with category ID = 0), then we generate a stream of child nodes until depth is less than 4. We use [`nonNullValues()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#nonNullValues--) to exclude the artificial `null` element from the stream, then use [`mapKeyValue()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#mapKeyValue-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to format an output string.